# Выскакивает странный текст после каждой команды в консоль, что это может быть?

Tags: reactjs, типы, nx

**Создал workspace nx dev и когда хотел запустить бэкенд то начало выдавать такой текст в терминале, раньше такого не было **

[image: Скрин текста]